# MySQL Combine Group by Column

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am new to SQL statements so my wording per my request may be incorrect, so I will provide a lot of detail to better understand my issue.

I have a database table called `workouts` that looks like this:

| id | bodyPart | gifUrl | name | target | broad_target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | back | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0007.gif | alternate lateral pulldown | lats | back |
| 2 | chest | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0009.gif | assisted chest dip (kneeling) | pectorals | chest |
| 3 | lower legs | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1708.gif | assisted lying calves stretch | calves | legs |
| 4 | upper legs | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1709.gif | assisted lying glutes stretch | glutes | legs |
| 5 | upper legs | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1710.gif | assisted lying gluteus and piriformis stretch | glutes | legs |
| 6 | back | http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0015.gif | assisted parallel close grip pull-up | lats | back |

and I want it to combine all the `broad_muscles` together and wrap it under an array called `data`.

Ideally, it would look like this:

```
{
    title: 'Leg',
    data:[
        {
      "bodyPart": "lower legs",
      "equipment": "assisted",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1708.gif",
      "id": "1708",
      "name": "assisted lying calves stretch",
      "target": "calves",
      "broad_target": "legs",
      "ppl": "legs"
    },
    {
      "bodyPart": "lower legs",
      "equipment": "smith machine",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1396.gif",
      "id": "1396",
      "name": "smith toe raise",
      "target": "calves",
      "broad_target": "legs",
      "ppl": "legs"
    }
  ]
}
```

I will return it via. Lambda in Node.JS, so if needed, the answer can be how to parse it in Node.JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `title: 'Leg'` and others too in the same manner like different objects?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, yes. I want `title: Leg` and all rows that have Leg as their title under an array called `data`

Comment: How is your data being returned from SQL in an array? If you can add sample data , it will be easy to answer.

Comment: Sure. My statement is just a `SELECT * FROM UserDB.Workouts`, and its output looks like ```{
    "id": 637,
    "bodyPart": "chest",
    "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0458.gif",
    "name": "floor fly (with barbell)",
    "target": "pectorals",
    "broad_target": "chest",
    "ppl": "push",
    "thumbnail": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584827386894-fc939dad6078?ixid=MnwzMDc4NzN8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxfHxiYXJiZWxsJTIwd29ya291dHxlbnwwfHx8fDE2NDY2MTgzNTc&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=296&q=20",
    "equipment": "barbell"
  }```

Comment: *and its output looks like* This is not MySQL output but its interpretation made by client software. *Ideally, it would look like this* Ideally, the desired output must match shown source data completely. In your output a value which is absent in source data can be found.

Comment: yes, thats after its returned in Node.js. in MYSQL, its just a table with columns and data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can something do like this, but if your o/p formats in an array. You should use any SQL orms that can be helpful.

```js
const sampleData = [{           
    "id":"1",
     "bodyPart":"back",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0007.gif",
      "name": "alternate lateral pulldown" ,    
      "target": "lats",
      "broad_target" : "back"
},{
 "id":"2",
     "bodyPart":"chest",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0007.gif",
      "name": "assisted chest dip (kneeling)" , 
      "target": "pectorals",
      "broad_target" : "chest"
},{
     "id":"2",
     "bodyPart":"upper legs",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0007.gif",
      "name": "assisted chest dip (kneeling)" , 
      "target": "glutes",
      "broad_target" : "legs"
},{
     "id":"2",
     "bodyPart":"lower legs",
      "gifUrl": "http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0007.gif",
      "name": "assisted chest dip (kneeling)" , 
      "target": "calves",
      "broad_target" : "legs"
}];

const matchString = "legs";

const output = sampleData.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (current?.broad_target === matchString) {
        prev['title'] = "Leg";
        prev['data'] = (prev['data'] || []);
        prev['data'].push(current);
    }
    return prev
},{});

console.log(output);
```

Note: I have taken sample o/p as the sample the information might not match the actual data.